# Constructing SimpMessagingTemplate instance without autowired

Tags: java, spring-websocket

I am trying to send asynchronous messages from a server to a client after the client is connected, independent of user action. All the examples I have found so far have the SimpMessagingTemplate autowired in the controller. Is there a file that contains information about how this object gets autowired by default? My goal is to use this object in a class that is not managed by spring. I would prefer to have a straight forward way to construct the object, instead of trying to recreate this deep object possibly with circular references through debug mode.

Here is the relevant part of the servlet xml:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/socketprefix">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/stompendpoint">

        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topics/,/queues/"/>

</websocket:message-broker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That template is usually autowired, because one is created for you that matches your configuration. It is, by design, coupled with other parts of your Simp infrastructure (and it has to be!), because to build one you need:

- the user destination prefix (if you configured a custom one)
- and more important, a [MessageChannel](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/MessageChannel.html) to send messages to your message broker

Maybe could you expand on why this class can't be Spring managed?

See [SimpMessagingTemplate javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessagingTemplate.html).